# BeautifulSoup4/CSS selector how to select the

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="myDivClass">
    <table class="myTableClass">
       <tr>
           <td>
               stuff-1A
               <table class="myTableClass">
                   <tr>
                       <td>stuff-1B</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               stuff-2A
               <table class="myTableClass">
                   <tr>
                       <td>stuff-2B</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               stuff-3A
               <table class="myTableClass">
                   <tr>
                       <td>stuff-3B</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Given a layout that looks like that, using beautifulSoup4 how can you select the td tags only from the main outer table (which contain sub-tables of the same class)?

I'm trying to use the .select() method.

So far I have

```
soup.select("div.myDivClass > table.myTableClass")
```

which returns the main outer table. But I need the td tags from that.

I tried

```
soup.select("div.myDivClass > table.myTableClass tr td")
```

But that returns all the td tags

**EDIT:** someone asked for the expected output

I'm not sure how exactly BeautifulSoups returns the .select() method,
But something like this

```
['<td>stuff-1a<table class="myTableClass"><tr><td>stuff-1B</td></tr></table></td>',

'<td>stuff-2a<table class="myTableClass"><tr><td>stuff-2B</td></tr></table></td>',

'<td>stuff-3a<table class="myTableClass"><tr><td>stuff-3B</td></tr></table></td>']
```

Which is an array of strings and the strings are the td tags of only the main outer table and their content in html

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Comment: just edited the post to add the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `> tr > td` instead of `tr td` to accomplish this task. Using the former you get only `tr` and then `td` elements that is direct child of the outer table you already managed to select :

```
div.myDivClass > table.myTableClass > tr > td
```

For reference : [MDN: Child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)